# Comparing one list to another with a custom class

Tags: c#, database, list

So I wonder if I can compare two Lists without using foreach because the List is with a custom class. Inside the class, it contains two variables. one of them is called GUID. In order to access the GUID for List A, I use Any(x =>x.guid) And to access the same things in List B I have to do a foreach, which is like this, foreach(var x in List B){x.guid).

What I want to know is, is it possible to do it without the foreach? And if it is possible, how? I have been looking for an answer online but most of the example is looking at an item in one list. What I'm trying to do is compare one custom list to another, but only one variable inside the class instead of comparing the whole class.

The code below is how I do it, comparing one to another, but is there a more efficient way to do it

```
List<MySecondGameList> myloadinglist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MySecondGameList>>(json);
            foreach (var id in myloadinglist)
            {
              if (GameData_List.my_loading_list.Any(x => x.guid == id.guid))
              {
                Debug.Log("Matching!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                continue;
              }    
           
              GameData_List.my_loading_list.Add(id);
              Debug.Log("It is loading");
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can *hide* loops within *Linq* queries, e.g.

```
List<MySecondGameList> myloadinglist = JsonConvert
  .DeserializeObject<List<MySecondGameList>>(json);
 
// HashSet<T> provides faster Contains than List
HashSet<Guid> existing = GameData_List
  .my_loading_list
  .Select(item => item.guid)
  .ToHashSet();

// We can put it compact with a help of AddRange instead of Add
GameData_List
  .my_loading_list
  .AddRange(myloadinglist.Where(item => !existing.Contains(item.guid)));
```